# Laravel Localization is not working in api.php route

Tags: php, laravel

I have some problem with my Laravel 5.6 project. I have created all my routes in `api.php` but **the localization is not working.**

When I create the routes in `web.php` the localization is working.

In `api.php` `setLocale`, `getLocale` functions working when I return the response, but it doesn't affect the `@lang('messages.smth')` or `{{ __('messages.smth) }}`. I think the route can't find the `(messages.smth)` but in `web.php` all are working correctly. Thanks

Comment: is there a middleware you have added to the `web` middleware group for localization purposes that isn't in the `api` middleware group?  if any of this involves sessions then you wouldn't have access to that in api routes by default.

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => ['locale']], function() {});

Comment: I have created all my routes inside this group routes middleware file

Comment: what does that middleware do, what does the request look like, what URI is being requested .. need some more information :)

Comment: @lagbox sorry but new here, I have some markdown problems

Comment: My LocaleMiddleware is like so public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $locale = app()->getLocale();
        if(session()->has('locale')) {
            $locale = session()->get('locale');
        }
        app()->setLocale($locale);
        
        return $next($request);
    }

Comment: you are using `sessions`, you do not have access to sessions without the `web` middleware group

Comment: @lagbox What do I need to use here if sessions doesn't work in api.php

Comment: I recommend you to see this example I hope this will help you.

https://medium.com/teknomuslim/multi-language-api-response-messages-in-laravel-5c9029a32e5c